# Pass Value from javascript to another jsp

Tags: javascript

I have a Javascript value from a.jsp and I want to pass the value of it to b.jsp.
how can it be done?

a.jsp

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var inspection_method_row_limit=50;

</script>
```

as example I want to pass to value of `inspection_method` which can be used in b.jsp.

Comment: How are you using that file? A Javascript file normally doesn't have a HTML script tag in them, the script tag is used in a page to include a Javascript file.

Comment: What's the relation between a.jsp and b.jsp? Depending on it, you probably want either AJAX or a hidden form input.

Comment: actually i dont know to pass value which use in javascript to another jsp file. how can i get it actually?

Answer (score 0):

In a.jsp, you need to forward to another jsp. I am assuming you will do it on a click of some anchor.

1. In javascript code, Make the final url. 
   `var forward_url = "/jsp/b.jsp?inspection_method_row_limit="+50;`
2. Update the location probably, on a click of an anchor tag...
   `<a href="window.location.href=forward_url">Forward</a>`.
3. In the target jsp, use the following...

   ```
   The value of inspection_method_row_limit is <b>
   <%= request.getParameter("inspection_method_row_limit") %></b>!
   ```

Comment: in case if i use the submit form then is it the same? got error when i declare var forward_url = /jsp/b.jsp?inspection_method_row_limit=50; in javascript. i use netbean to deploy the program in apache tomcat.

Comment: Edited to include quotes around. When you use form submission, post your complete code.

Comment: where ? (probably due to spilled code, it is not visible at all)

Comment: As a first point, let us know if you have installed tomcat or any jsp server. because without which our discussions wont lead to any fruitful outcome.

Comment: ya.. i had installed tomcat. it work normally. but now i cant find solution to pass value inside javascript from one jsp to another jsp. actually, what kind of solution or method which i can pass value in javascript to another jsp

Comment: where are the paths to a.jsp and b.jsp - full paths including your server name _may be localhost_ (should be accessible through browser with errorless compilation)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var inspection_method_row_limit=0;
var deleted_row_inspection_method="";

function myCreateFunction(tableID) {

    var ClickMax = 5;
    if (inspection_method_row_limit < ClickMax){
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var x = inspection_method_row_limit + 1;
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var element1 = document.createElement("input");
    element1.type = "checkbox";
    element1.name="chkbox[]";
    cell1.appendChild(element1);

//compare if no deleted row before then enter if statement and numbering is follow inspection_method_row_limit

if (deleted_row_inspection_method == ""){

    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    cell2.innerHTML = x;

    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var element2 = document.createElement("textarea");
    element2.type = "textarea";        
    var txt = tableID + x;
    element2.name = txt;
    element2.className = "textarea2";
    cell3.appendChild(element2);
    }

//if user had deleted row before then the numbering of previously will be reuse

else
    {
    var stringlength = deleted_row_inspection_method.length;
    var foundLocation = deleted_row_inspection_method.search("-");
    var subStringname = deleted_row_inspection_method.substring(0,foundLocation);
    deleted_row_inspection_method = deleted_row_inspection_method.slice(foundLocation + 1,stringlength);

    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    cell2.innerHTML = subStringname;

    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var element2 = document.createElement("textarea");
    element2.type = "textarea";   
    element2.name = tableID + subStringname;
    element2.className = "textarea2";
    cell3.appendChild(element2);
    }
    inspection_method_row_limit ++;
    }

function myDeleteFunction(tableID) {

//delete row for inspection method

        try {
        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;

        for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
            var row = table.rows[i];
            var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
            if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
                var res = row.cells[1].innerHTML + "-";
                deleted_row_inspection_method = deleted_row_inspection_method.concat(res);
                table.deleteRow(i);
                rowCount--;
                i--;
                inspection_method_row_limit --;
            }
            }
        }catch(e) {
            alert(e);
        }
</script>       

<form action="index.html?pageid=inspection_session&content=inspection_summary_result" name="form1" id="form1" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm(document.form1)" >


<tr>
<td width="300" height="100"><font style="font-size:18px">2. Inspection Method <img src="images/information.png" width="20" height="20" align="absmiddle" style="cursor:pointer;" title="Add Row for More Data" alt="Add Row for More Data"></font></td>
<td valign="top">
<button type="button" class="mybtn" onclick="myCreateFunction('inspection_method')"><img align="absmiddle" src="icons/action_add.png"/>&nbsp;Add Row</button>
<button type="button" class="mybtn" onclick="myDeleteFunction('inspection_method')"><img align="absmiddle" src="icons/action_remove.png"/>&nbsp;Delete Row</button>

<table id="inspection_method" border="1">
<tr>
<td width="50"><img src="images/001_06.gif" width="20" height="20" align="absmiddle" style="cursor:pointer;" title="Tick to Delete" alt="Tick to Delete"></td>
<td width="50">No.</td>
<td width="589">Description</td>
</tr>
</table><br>
</td>
</tr>

<table>
<tr>
<td height="45" colspan="4"><input type="submit" name="submit"  class="mybtn3"  value="Next"/> <input type="reset" class="mybtn3" name="reset" value="Reset"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```